# Is there an equivalent of Valgrind for .Net on Windows?

Tags: .net, windows, debugging

I want to debug some managed code (originally written in C# on Windows x86). I know that Valgrind has a great set of tools for unmanaged code on a few non-Windows platforms. However, we are talking about Windows and managed .Net code here. So, is there an equivalent of Valgrind for .Net on Windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some profilers for .NET:

- [Microsoft CLR Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx) (free)
- [RedGate ANTS Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) (commercial)
- [JetBrains dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) (commercial)

Comment: The download link for CLR Profiler still works. So, I'll use that thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See our [C# Profiler](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Profilers/CSharpProfiler.html) (commercial).